# Spark install error on Ubuntu 14.04 missing javac?

Tags: java, ubuntu, installation, javac

I was installing Spark on my Ubuntu 14.04 and it seemed to be going smoothly for quite a while then bombed with I have previously installed and checked Scala... and see details of Java at bottom..

```
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
[error] (streaming-flume-sink/compile:compile) java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64/bin/javac": error=2,    No such file or directory
[error] (unsafe/compile:compile) java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64/bin/javac": error=2, No such file or directory
[error] (network-common/compile:compile) java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64/bin/javac": error=2, No such file or directory
[error] (launcher/compile:compile) java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64/bin/javac": error=2, No such file or directory
[error] Total time: 737 s, completed Nov 9, 2015 4:37:48 PM
```

I have Java installed:

```
tom@tom-sam:~$ java -version
java version "1.7.0_85"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (IcedTea 2.6.1) (7u85-2.6.1-5ubuntu0.14.04.1)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 24.85-b03, mixed mode)
```

Any ideas??

Comment: Are you sure that java bits are present at bin folder `/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64/bin/`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I have Java installed:
>
> ```
> tom@tom-sam:~$ java -version
> java version "1.7.0_85"
> OpenJDK Runtime Environment (IcedTea 2.6.1) (7u85-2.6.1-5ubuntu0.14.04.1)
> OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 24.85-b03, mixed mode)
> ```

You have the java runtime installed (the JRE). You need the JDK (Java Developer Kit). You can install the [Oracle JDK](http://ubuntuhandbook.org/index.php/2014/02/install-oracle-java-6-7-or-8-ubuntu-14-04/), or the [OpenJDK](http://openjdk.java.net/projects/jdk8/). For the OpenJDK, it should be as simple as

```
$ sudo apt-get install default-jdk
```

For the Oracle JDK, it's only a little more involved,

```
$ sudo apt-get install python-software-properties
$ sudo add-apt-repository ppa:webupd8team/java
$ sudo apt-get update
```

Then one of

```
$ sudo apt-get install oracle-java6-installer
```

or

```
$ sudo apt-get install oracle-java7-installer
```

or

```
$ sudo apt-get install oracle-java8-installer
```

For Java 6, 7 or 8 respectively.